# Can the dependent of a G4 visa holder work as an unpaid intern without an EAD?

Tags: usa, employment

As the 18-year-old child of a G4 visa holder, can I apply for and accept an unpaid internship at a private company without obtaining an EAC?

Comment: I think you can trust the IMF: https://www.imf.org/external/np/adm/rec/policy/oth/depwkauth.htm

Comment: @mkennedy I don't see anything on that page that sheds any light on the present question.

Comment: A G4 dependent must have an EAD.

Comment: @mkennedy but the page you link to does not discuss unpaid employment.  I don't doubt that you are correct, but it's not obvious from that document.

Comment: Ah, sorry,my mistake. I missed the "unpaid" qualifier. I'm mainly finding university website that talk about unpaid internships/volunteering on F-1 or J-1 visas. They say that if it's a true unpaid internship--no remuneration, no goods, no gifts, no payment after the fact, doesn't replace an employee, no employee benefits, etc. you don't need to get an EAD. Whether that applies for a G-4, I haven't been able to determine.

Comment: Ex. https://www.naceweb.org/public-policy-and-legal/legal-issues/legal-issues-international-students-and-unpaid-internships/

Comment: @mkennedy it should be the same for G-4 (and for B-1 for that matter), though there may be court precedent that I don't know about that makes it different.